# Lost Dogmeat in fallout 4

Tags: fallout-4

I ran into an issue today. I was with nick valentine on the Kelloggs mission when we came across some super mutants. I tried to fight them off but they were too strong, so I hid in a nearby shed. Nick followed me but dogmeat didn't. Once I regened health I went back out to fight them. But they were already dead. (Dogmeat must of killed them.) But I couldn't find dogmeat. I searched for quite a while before giving up. So I then went to Google and someone said to try: `prid 1d162` and then `recycleactor` then I checked red rocket and saw him there. But when I tried to do anything it showed the "Press E to talk" message so I did. I said something like "We're gonna need you to find Kellogg." And he won't follow me or anything. He's stuck on the Kelloggs mission or something. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on personal recollection and [this guide](http://www.usgamer.net/articles/fallout-4-reunions-follow-dogmeat-kill-kellogg), Dogmeat will lead you to where Kellogg is, but you must follow him. If you stray from the quest, Dogmeat will not follow you. He will not be available as a usual follower until you make it into Kellogg's hideout.

I had a similar issue where I made it to the hideout but didn't bother to go in and I couldn't use Dogmeat until I continued the quest.

For reference, Dogmeat will lead you to

> Fort Hagen

Comment: Ok, how do I get back on track with the quest? I'm at the red rocket with him.

Comment: Uh if he's not leading you to the hideout, I'm not sure. I did this without console commands. Not sure if you glitches it or not. I'm sure there's a way to get to the hideout without Dogmeat. Getting there should make him usable as a follower again, though.

Comment: Getting into the fort should definitely do it. You can just ignore Dogmeat on that mission if you want. He teleports to you each time you reach the next piece of evidence and returns home when you get to the fort.